# Android App Rejection due to Data safety issue

Tags: android, google-play-developer-api

Your recent app submission has been rejected for not adhering to the Google Play Developer Programme Policies. We've sent more information to the account owner's email address. Address any issues and make sure that your app meets all policy requirements before resubmitting.
[image]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

please go to your google console -> select your App -> in the left side bar under policy(at the bottom) -> click on App content -> then click on privacy policy and enter your url.

If above solution not work then check your data sefty options.

Comment: i have added privacy policy URL but again app rejected 
data safety issue

Comment: If you are taking permissions or user's data like email, phone number or name. You need to clearify that things in data safety.

Take refrence:

https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/10787469?hl=en#:~:text=Open%20Play%20Console%20and%20go,you'll%20need%20to%20provide.